# How to query the latest date from each duplicated name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question to query tuple(s) that have latest date of each name.

This is my example table.

```
ID || NAM E     || DATE              || INFOA || INFOB || INFOC
1  || Alice     || 2015-08-20 12:0:0 || Y     || N     || Y
2  || Bob       || 2015-08-20 12:0:0 || Y     || N     || Y
3  || Cheschire || 2015-08-20 12:0:0 || N     || Y     || Y
4  || Alice     || 2015-08-25 12:0:0 || N     || Y     || N
5  || Bob       || 2015-08-15 12:0:0 || Y     || Y     || N
```

Query I used

```
SELECT NAME, MAX(DATE), INFOA, INFOB, INFOC
FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
GROUP BY NAME,INFOA,INFOB,INFOC
```

Result is...

```
Alice     || 2015-08-20 12:0:0 || Y || N || Y
Bob       || 2015-08-20 12:0:0 || Y || N || Y
Cheschire || 2015-08-20 12:0:0 || N || Y || Y
Alice     || 2015-08-25 12:0:0 || N || Y || N
Bob       || 2015-08-15 12:0:0 || Y || Y || N
```

But my expected result is...

```
Bob       || 2015-08-20 12:0:0 || Y || N || Y
Cheschire || 2015-08-20 12:0:0 || N || Y || Y
Alice     || 2015-08-25 12:0:0 || N || Y || N
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you specify your which sql you use like mysql,sqlServer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
DECLARE @userData TABLE(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    INFOA VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    INFOB VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    INFOC VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @userData VALUES ('1','Alice','2015-08-20 12:0:0','Y','N','Y')
INSERT INTO @userData VALUES ('2','Bob','2015-08-20 12:0:0','Y','N','Y')
INSERT INTO @userData VALUES ('3','Cheschire','2015-08-20 12:0:0','N','Y','Y')
INSERT INTO @userData VALUES ('4','Alice','2015-08-25 12:0:0','N','Y','N')
INSERT INTO @userData VALUES ('5','Bob','2015-08-15 12:0:0','Y','Y','N')

SELECT a.ID,a.Name,a.Date, a.INFOA,a.INFOB,a.INFOC FROM (
select *,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) AS [Rank]
 from @userData
 ) a  where a.[Rank] = 1
ORDER BY a.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row if there are no other row with same name but a later date:

```
select *
from tablename t1
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.name = t1.name
                    and t2.date > t1.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below:

```
CREATE TABLE T1(AA varchar2(10),bb TIMESTAMP(6),cc varchar2(1),dd varchar2(1),ee varchar2(1));

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('a',systimestamp-5,'Y','N','Y');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('b',systimestamp-5,'N','N','Y');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('c',systimestamp-5,'N','Y','Y');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('a',systimestamp-1,'N','Y','N');
insert into t1 values ('b',systimestamp-11,'Y','Y','N');
```

Now, below is the query I used to get output you wanted:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE (t1.aa, T1.BB) IN (SELECT aa, MAX(BB)
                         from t1 group by aa);
```

Output:

```
b   21-AUG-15 02.51.47.000000000 AM N   N   Y
c   21-AUG-15 02.51.47.000000000 AM N   Y   Y
a   25-AUG-15 02.51.48.000000000 AM N   Y   N
```

Note: as per your question, you required latest date for each name (no matter what other values would be)

Answer (score 0):

use below query to get the results as you expected

```
select id,name,date1,infoa,infob,infoc
    from 
    (
    select id,name,date1, row_number() over (partition by name order by date1 desc) as s
    ,infoa,infob,infoc
    from testpart
    )
    where s=1
    order by date1
```